# Let me choose not to include tags in Resume/CV export

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I feel like the inclusion of tags in the exported version of your resume from careers should be optional or should be styled to be slightly more distinct.  They look fine within the application but they sort of just look like dangling words and visual noise in the PDF export.  I'm not sure they're always desirable in the print version.  Just curious if anyone else has similar thoughts?